# How do conflicting breach modifiers stack?

Tags: xcom-chimera-squad

[image: Breach entrance with the "Closely Watched" (Enemies deal +1 damage during breach) AND "Hard to Hit" (Enemies deal -1 damage during the breach) modifiers]

What's going on here? Do these just cancel out and this breach entrance effectively has no modifiers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they cancel each other out.

The modifiers are generated randomly, though the amount of positive and negative modifiers itself does appear to be fixed). The game doesn't exclude modifiers that cancel each other out, and this is one such case.

Whether that's by design or not is up for debate and not meaningfully answerable other than by the developers themselves.

Note that a [mod](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2074088369) was released that addresses this issue.

Comment: Looks like the ability to get conflicting breach modifiers was removed in the [latest patch](https://support.2k.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048137774-XCOM-Chimera-Squad-Patch-Notes-May-20th-2020).